# Modprobe stalling in Kali Linux during installation of 88XXau wifi driver

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux, kernel-modules, modprobe

I am trying to install a wifi driver for the TP-Link Archer T9UH v1 in Kali Linux. The following causes modprobe to stall:

```
root@CODE-K:~# modprobe 88XXau --verbose
insmod /lib/modules/5.3.0-kali3-amd64/updates/88XXau.ko
```

and it's been stuck on insmod for about 20 minutes.

Here's some other system info:

```
root@CODE-K:~# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 18a5:0304 Verbatim, Ltd Store 'n' Go
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2357:0106 TP-Link Archer T9UH v1 [Realtek RTL8814AU]
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c040 Logitech, Inc. Corded Tilt-Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c31d Logitech, Inc. Media Keyboard K200
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@CODE-K:~# uname -r
5.3.0-kali3-amd64
```

Comment: Kali is known to have issues with many wifi drivers. That's because Kali is meant for [penetration testing](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). If you want to hack wifi, the simplest solution is **not to use Kali**. Use some Debian based distro instead (Kali is Debian based), and you'll have all the hacking tools Kali has (though you need to install them), but none of the trouble. Kali is **not** "what all the hackers use", no matter what you read on some forums.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at that. Are there any mass package installers that you can recommend?

Comment: Also, @dirkt, is Parrot OS any better in terms of wifi support?

Comment: I don't know Parrot OS. On plain Debian, ca. 15 years ago, before Kali even existed, running e.g. `airodump-ng` was as simple as `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng` and then running it. If you are new to all this, you'll want to get familiar with the tools one-by-one, so installing each one before you try it isn't actually a burden. Getting familiar with the package manager of whatever distro you choose also doesn't hurt. There are mass installer scripts, but this way you'll get to know things much better.

Comment: I've been using pentesting distros for about 3 years. However, ever since the new kali upgrade and kernel 5.3, it seems that the wifi stopped working